# Cookie manager extension for Firefox that allows to import cookies into a certain temporary container

Tags: firefox, cookies, browser-extension

There are a lot of cookie manager extensions for Firefox, and some of them allow to import cookies from the clipboard or from a file. I believe that I know nearly all of them.

However, I am using multiple Firefox installations on different PCs with [Multi Account Containers](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/containers) and [Temporary Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/temporary-containers/). From time to time, I would like to export all cookies from a certain container into a file on one PC and import these cookies **into a certain container** on another PC.

The former (export cookies from a certain container) is a no-brainer since some extensions are able to do that out of the box (e.g., [Cookie Quick Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/android/addon/cookie-quick-manager/)). But I couldn't find a solution for the latter (import cookies into a certain container).

Does anybody know of an extension that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck.

Quick Cookie Manager does exactly what you want.

The trick is to export cookies from a container, and then ensure the same container exists before performing the import operation.

A successful technique is to create a ***permanent*** container with the same name in both the *source* and *target* Firefox profiles.  Use that ***permanent*** container to store your desired cookies.  You will then be able to easily transfer the cookies in that container between profiles.

You can also implement the above technique with multiple ***permanent*** containers that are duplicated across multiple Firefox profiles.  This allows for isolation between several sets of cookies.

Furthermore, because the exported cookies are stored in a human-readable format, you can even edit the export file by hand to adjust to which container the cookies will be imported.

This extension is fully compatible with the Multi Account Containers and Temporary Containers extensions.

This Firefox extension is a rare **Mozilla Recommended** extension, which means Mozilla ensures it meets "the highest standards in security, functionality, and overall user experience".

It is available from AMO here:
https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/cookie-quick-manager/

And on GitHub here:
https://github.com/ysard/cookie-quick-manager

Comment: Thank you very much, and +1. However, I am already using Cookie Quick Manager, but the destination system has other containers than the source system. Hence, I first have to find out the raw number of the destination container, which is really annoying (starting at `about:debugging`), then I have to adjust the raw container number in the exported cookie file before importing it. This really sucks, so I hoped that there is an extension that allows to import a cookie file, providing a dropdown to choose the destination container. I'll open a feature request on Github :-)

Comment: @Binarus You're welcome.  I think opening the feature request on GitHub is a good idea.  That said, I think it can basically do what you want, but not in the most user-friendly way.  Give me a few minutes, and I'll add additional details for you to the answer I wrote.

Comment: @Binarus I added more detail that I hope helps you.  Feel free to ask questions, and I'll help you the best I can.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't test right now, but your suggestion to use permanent containers absolutely makes sense. This probably means that permanent containers don't have *random* raw IDs that internally identify them, but have IDs that are based on their name only. I'll investigate this in a week or so.

Comment: @Binarus You're most welcome! Yes, IIRC the IDs will be useful with permanent containers.  If not, a simple script that employs `sed` can be used to edit the data file.  It's been a minute (as the kids say - still getting used to that one) since I successfully resolved a few issues using the technique I outlined, but it definitely worked.  If you run into any challenges just let me know, and I'll lend a hand.  And if you don't run into any challenges, always great to hear back if you get everything working successfully!